# How to extract unique read IDs from a fastq file?

Tags: uniq, fastq, ids

I want to extract all the unique read IDs in a fastq file and output the unique read IDs to a text file. (I have done the same task for bam files using the samtools but I don't know any tools that would handle fastq files.)

**for BAM files:**  samtools view input.bam|cut -f1 | sort | uniq  >> unique.reads.txt

**for fastq:** (need help)

*Looking for a one-liner command or a tool that can do that.*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using seqkit (no need to sort):
here you basically:

1. transform fastq to tab
2. create an array with $1 (read id) and then run through this array, printing ids in the output file

`seqkit fx2tab reads.fq | awk -v OFS='\t' '{array[$1]=1} END {for (readID in array) print readID}' > unique.reads.txt`

also you can do this:
`seqkit fx2tab reads.fq | cut -f 1 | sort | uniq > unique.reads.txt`

but then you'll need to sort the file first

or almost the same but without seqkit:
`grep "@" reads.fq | sort | uniq > unique.reads.txt`

`grep "@" reads.fq | awk -v OFS='\t' '{array[$1]=1} END {for (readID in array) print readID}' > unique.reads.txt`

but I in general like seqkit, always advertise it